# Unable to send sendBroadcast from SyncAdapter to Activity

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, localbroadcastmanager

I have an application with a `SyncAdapter` that runs fine. The `SyncService` runs once per hour.

My application has a main `FragmentActivity` called `DeviceControlActivity` and I would like to receive messages from the SyncAdaptor, such as the `syncResult`.

I've tried a lot to get it up and running, but I'm not able to receive any messages on `DeviceControlActivity` from `SyncAdapter`.

In my `DeviceControlActivity` I do:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mSyncMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got it!");
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Receive feedback from syncManager
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplication()).registerReceiver(mSyncMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Constants.MESSAGE_SYNC));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mSyncMessageReceiver);
}
```

On the SyncAdapter, I have:

```
private LocalBroadcastManager mBroadcastManager;

public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);


    mBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(
        Account account,
        Bundle extras,
        String authority,
        ContentProviderClient provider,
        SyncResult syncResult) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.MESSAGE_SYNC);
    mBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I can send messages from `DeviceControlActivity` to itself and it works.

I can receive messages from the SyncService, but using an alternative way:

```
final int mask = ContentResolver.SYNC_OBSERVER_TYPE_PENDING | ContentResolver.SYNC_OBSERVER_TYPE_ACTIVE;
mSyncMonitor = ContentResolver.addStatusChangeListener(mask, this);
```

This listener reports the sync activity as expected.

But I would like to use a LocalBroadcastManager to communicate between the Service and the Activity, but I'm not able.

I've already check related questions like [How to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) documentation this class is a *Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects **within your process***.

The above example dos not work if the `<service>` runs on a different process.

The `AndroidManifest.xml` was:

```
<service
            android:name=".sync.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync">
```

This is the way suggested in [Creating a Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).

If we change the `<service>` declaration to:

```
    <service
        android:name=".sync.SyncService"
        android:exported="true">
```

removing the `android:process` property, the `SyncService`will run in the same process and the `LocalBroadcastManager` will work.

Comment: Doing same but broadcastreciever not getting fired in Oreo + devices ....
Whats the way to handle it ?